# How to get list back from a ListStore GWT

Tags: java, oop, gwt, gxt

Well i'm with a problem in GWT(gxt).

I have a grid in my screen editable and I put itens in that grid with a List, but after edit this grid I need this List again to save in DB what should I do?

something like this:

```
public ListStore<MdlFormDic> store = new ListStore<MdlFormDic>();
store.add(list);
//how to get list from the store?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `store.getModels()` to get ListStore models.

Hope it helps.